# Vertically align elements on the page while keeping equal heights

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make each element in the same row equal height. I don't want elements to be stretched though. They should also be vertically aligned within the page. I managed to get them vertically aligned on the page using `align-items:center;` However, the boxes in the same row aren't of equal heights. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I don't want to use a fixed height to achieve this though.
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/wiroculuvu/edit?html,css,output)

I'm looking to achieve this;[image]

Many thanks.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.help-boxes {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-wrap {
  height: 92vh;
}

.help-box-link {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(22, 28, 45, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(22, 28, 45, 0.175);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 0 0 31.33%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="help-boxes">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D - not sure I understood it though. In my example, .help-boxes isn't the parent you are looking for?

Comment: I just want the boxes in one row to be of same height but the whole set (all six boxes) align vertically on the page, if that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks but not quite as the boxes have now stretched even when content is not that tall.

Comment: Well you can't have the "equal height" without stretching so I don't see what else you want. - https://jsbin.com/taganunoji/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I'm after this output - https://ibb.co/qCjBD17 
Is this not achievable?

Comment: Just updated the thread with an image showing my desired output. Not sure if that's achievable though. Thanks

Comment: So this - https://jsbin.com/quqaguxezo/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using grid.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.box-wrap{ 
  height: 94vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.help-boxes{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.help-box-link {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(22, 28, 45, 0.175);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 0 0 31.33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="help-boxes">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Trapti. By adding display: flex to the .box-wrap and with your grid approach it seems to be getting closer to what I wanted to achieve. Many thanks for your help! Never have used gird - guess it's time to look up some tuts :)

Comment: @con: A grid is perfectly suited for this type of layout. Unlike the flex box, that allows you to control 1 dimension only, a grid is a 2D layout. You get to control columns *and* rows. [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) provides a good overview.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex for the child too and remove the `align-items` in the parent, instead use it in your child.

```css
body {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.help-boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.box-wrap {
  height: 92vh;
}

.help-box-link {
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem rgba(22, 28, 45, 0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 3rem
    rgba(22, 28, 45, 0.175);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 2% 1em;
    padding: 1rem;
    flex: 1 0 31.33%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="help-boxes">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
    <a href="#" role="button" class="help-box-link">
      <p class="help-box__desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I'm after as the boxes have now stretched.I'm after this - https://ibb.co/qCjBD17

Answer (score -1):

In `.help-boxes` class make this alteration

```
align-items: stretch; // Alter this line of 'center' to 'stretch'
```

This way all the boxes will align based on the largest of them.

Comment: Thanks @Caio but I don't want the boxes to be stretched.